# How can I make Internet Explorer run faster with Selenium?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, selenium

I'm facing a problem with Internet Explorer while automating scripts with selenium. It is so slow that my scripts time out.

I am using a CSS locator for automation. Can anyone tell me how can we increase the speed of Selenium automated tests?

Comment: What are you using? Selenium RC or Selenium 2 (WebDriver)?

Answer (score 1):

Try with IE webdriver it will not support css3 but still faster. If you want to write test using standard selelenium api then use webdriverbacked selenium or try using ISFW with browser string as iexplorerDriver or iexplorerRemoteDriver. We also face speed issue in case of IE and we utilized webdriver support provided by [ISFW](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#testing-frameworks).

Comment: I downloaded that we have same framework only i found there is ISFW-plugin.xpi file but how to use it. And i think it is a FF browser plugin file, which is not running on IE. Could you explain how to go further ?????????

Comment: ISFW-plugin facilitate to export your recorded steps in IDE to ISFW format. After Export you can run test against any selenium supported browsers. For that you need to set browser name in application.properties or in xml configuration file by providing parameter. If you read the documentation provided with zip then you can get more idea. For simple evaluation just run demo test provided in zip by setting browser string to iexplorerDriver or iexplorerRemoteDriver you will get idea.I am writing steps which we did after download the zip in separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts finding elements is very rare!

It may be that the machine that you are running your tests on is being starved of resources. CSS selectors use javascript, from Sizzle, to find objects.

Try check that it has more resources, like CPU and RAM, and then see if that helps.

Comment: I found that IE is slow due to website contains flash and javascript not due to less RAM or CPU. So can you suggest anything about on that point. The site i want to automate is containing flash and javascript. Did you have any solution ?????

Answer (score 0):

As i discussed in comment to your question, here are steps that i took after downloading the zip

1. extracted to one dir say `project-home`
2. Downloaded selenium-standalone-server jar and placed under `project-home/server`
3. I found some sample tests under `project-home/src` dir so executed batch file `project-home/scripts/seleniumTestRunner.bat` to get the demo.

I found tests run in Firefox as the
`selenium.defaultBrowser=*firefox`
in `project-home/resources/application.properties` file. I had then tried by changing values with different browser string and found working fine.

For IE use *iehta or *iexplore

```
selenium.defaultBrowser=*iehta
```

For IE webdriver use

```
selenium.defaultBrowser=iexplorerDriver
```

For IE remote webdriver use

```
selenium.defaultBrowser=iexplorerRemoteDriver
```

I also wrote one additional test by taking ref from sample code and worked fine.

Usage for IDE plug-in

1. install xpi
2. record new test
3. Exported test : file-> Export TestCase As -> InfostretchFW Format
4. provide filename with .java extention
5. Save under project-home\src\com\sample\automation\tests

There are some useful functionality added by [IDE plug-in](http://blog.infostretch.com/?p=1106). Following are additional commands provided by it

1. DefineModule
2. EndModule
3. IF, EndIF
4. else, elseIf
5. While, EndWhile

   Hope this information will help you. I got all above help from InfoStretch support center some time back! :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Selenium RC, you can migrate to WebDriver (Selenium 2). WebDriver (Selenium 2) is faster than Selenium RC.
id is better to find out element. It is good as you are using CSS Locator, because using css locator is faster than xpath. So in this point you are in right track.